# Cannot curl from docker host to container

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, curl, docker-compose

Looking for help with weird problem with docker.

I have:

- host machine with Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
- Docker version 20.10.18, build b40c2f6
- docker compose with Sonatype Nexus:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  nexus:
    image: sonatype/nexus3
    container_name: nexus
    volumes:
      - "nexus-data:/nexus-data"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:91:8081"
      - "INTERNAL_ADDRESS:91:8081"
      - "EXTERNAL_ADDRESS:91:8081"
    networks:
      - nexus
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1  
volumes:
  nexus-data: {}
networks:
  nexus:
    driver: bridge
    name: docker_network
    enable_ipv6: false
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "172.1.0.0/16"
          gateway: "172.1.0.1"
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.enable_ipv6: "false"
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: docker_network
```

So...container starting normally and I can open web pages:
http://EXTERNAL_ADDRESS:91/ (from internet),
http://INTERNAL_ADDRESS:91/ (from local network)

Also I can do `curl http://EXTERNAL_ADDRESS:91/` from internet.

By I can't do `curl http://***:91/` from the host itself.

```
curl -v http://localhost:91/
* Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 91 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:91
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>

curl -v http://INTERNAL_ADDRESS:91/
* Trying INTERNAL_ADDRESS...
* TCP_NODELAY set

(!!! and that all for this address)
```

Also I have iptables enabled and set up on host machine, I tried to totally disabled them and it doesn't help. Here they are:

```
# clean table
sudo iptables -F DOCKER-USER
# allow outgoing from docker and established
sudo iptables -A DOCKER-USER -i docker0 -j RETURN
sudo iptables -A DOCKER-USER -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A DOCKER-USER -i docker_network -j RETURN
sudo iptables -A DOCKER-USER -o docker_network -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# allow custom ip and localhost/internal network
sudo iptables -A DOCKER-USER -o docker0 -s MY_OWN_IP_ADDRESS -p tcp -j RETURN
sudo iptables -A DOCKER-USER -o docker_network -s MY_OWN_IP_ADDRESS -p tcp -j RETURN
sudo iptables -A DOCKER-USER -i $INTERNAL_INTERFACE -p tcp -j RETURN
sudo iptables -A DOCKER-USER -i $LOCALHOST_INTERFACE -p tcp -j RETURN
# reject all other
sudo iptables -A DOCKER-USER -j REJECT
```

Other services (that are not in docker) are totally accessible in any way: web page, curl, wget.

Any advice to fix it?

Comment: Does your system have more interfaces than this that you don't want to publish to?  If you just use `ports: ['91:8081']` without specifying an IP address, Docker will bind the port to all host interfaces, and this might be a little simpler.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, I have multiple interfaces, and prefer explicitly set them. But I tried remove ip addresses and map only port 91:8081. Unfortunately it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of investigation I've found the cause of my problem: my iptables rules.

At the end of rules list I have this (to block all requests that not meet other allowed rules):

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

So all requests to docker containers were blocked.
I've added 2 rules (before DROP) for docker network and curl is working now:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i docker_network -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o docker_network -j ACCEPT
```